# Need a Java Lambda equivalent

Tags: java, lambda

In scala:

```
val parseInt = (s: String) => s.toInt
val num=parseInt.apply("10")
```

maps to in Java:

```
Function<String, Integer> parseInt = (String s) -> Integer.parseInt(s);
Integer num= parseInt.apply("10");
```

Alternative:
In Scala:

```
val parseInt = (s: String) => s.toInt
val num=parseInt("10")
```

what is the equivalent in Java for

```
val num=parseInt("10")?
```

Comment: you need to format the code to make it easily understandable

Comment: While Scala allows both versions (`val num=parseInt.apply("10")` and `val num=parseInt("10")`), in Java it's always `Integer num = parseInt.apply("10");`

Comment: `Integer num= parseInt.apply("10");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get rid of `apply` using a lambda, however you can create a separate static method with the same visibility:

```
static Integer parseInt(String s) { return Integer.parseInt(s); }
```

Comment: But then you have to create a class which beats the whole purpose. Thanks. Are you sure we cannot eliminate the call to apply?

Comment: @Raster your code `Integer num = parseInt.apply("10");` is already in a class, you can just add the method to that class. Otherwise no, you can't remove the `apply`.

Answer (score 3):

The Java equivalent is the static method: [Integer.parseInt(String str)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: Lets try to forget about Integer class. Lets see what we can do in terms of the custom function that is being created. Thanks. Mainly what can we do to avoid using apply()